# TermDocumentMatrix sometimes throwing error

Tags: r, word-cloud, term-document-matrix

I am creating a Word Cloud based on Tweets from various different sports teams. This code executes successfully about 1 in 10 times:

```
handle <- 'arsenal'
txt <- searchTwitter(handle,n=1000,lang='en')
t <- sapply(txt,function(x) x$getText())
t <- gsub('http.*\\s*|RT|Retweet','',t)
t <- gsub(handle,'',t)
t_c <- Corpus(VectorSource(t))
tdm = TermDocumentMatrix(t_c,control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,stopwords = stopwords("english"),removeNumbers = TRUE, content_transformer(tolower)))
m = as.matrix(tdm)
word_freqs = sort(rowSums(m), decreasing=TRUE) 
dm = data.frame(word=names(word_freqs), freq=word_freqs)
wordcloud(dm$word, dm$freq, random.order=FALSE, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"),rot.per=0.5)
```

The other 9 out of 10 times, it throws the following error:

```
Error in simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow = length(allTerms),  : 
  'i, j, v' different lengths
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
2: In simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow = length(allTerms),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Any ideas guys? I've googled, but so far have come up short! Keep in mind I'm an absolute newbie in R!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after a bit of playing around, the following line of code has completely fixed my issue:

```
t <- iconv(t,to="utf-8-mac")
```

Comment: Can confirm this fixed my problem immediately (running on Mac).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have used the following line of code somewhere before using **DocumentTermMatrix** command.

```
corpus = tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
```

This line of code converts all text in the corpus to PlainTextDocument, on which the **DocumentTermMatrix** function does not work properly.

Just repeat entire process of creating the corpus and preprocessing it skipping the above command and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove:

```
corpus = tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
```

you also have to remove:

```
t_c <- Corpus(VectorSource(t))
```

Then you'll get the right output for `TermDocumentMatrix`.